# Equation of a circle in 3D

Tags: geometry

Does the equation x^2 + y^2 = 9 represent a circle in 3D?

I know it is the general equation of a circle, and it may be a silly question, but the "3D" term is causing confusion. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the 3-dimensional graph of $x^2+y^2=9$.

When $z$=0, the surface's cross section will be a circle of radius 3 centered at the origin.

When $z$ = anything, the surface's cross section will be a circle of radius 3 centered at the origin.

When you stack these cross sections and consider all values of $z$, you get a cylinder (vertically along the $z$-axis) of radius 3 centered at the origin.

Comment: Did you mean to write $x^2+y^2=z^2$?

Comment: thats a cone right

Comment: Yes, but you write "z=0", and you haven't mentioned $z$ anywhere before that. Please clarify it. Thank you.

Comment: They mentioned it was 3d, inferring a z-axis. @Lovsovs